# SSIS Import All Worksheets From Excel Workbook To New Tables

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2012

I have a workbook with 15 worksheets.  How can I import each worksheet into a different table in SQL Server 2008?  The caveat is that the tables do not exist, I want them to be created on import.  How can this be achieved with a SSIS package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS will at BEST suggest data types for each worksheet but you will still have to manually confirm the create table statement for the metadata of each sheet. There is no automated way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Ah, I have never used SSIS - I was thinking it would be close to the Import Wizard where it automagically creates field types/lengths.  Based off your answer, I will have to create the tables then import the data into them, is that accurate?

Comment: It does "automagically" create the field types and lengths but a) it's not always right b) you have to point it to your worksheet and it has to detect the metadata to do that to create the table within SSIS. it cannot do this on the fly during the package run. this has to be done within the package as part of the data source then you can output it into the destination (which is where it will generate the create table code for you) but since the source and destination are separate, you need to connect the two first before it will generate the table.